# Type mapping in Doctrine 2 DBAL

Tags: php, mysql, database, doctrine-orm, dbal

I am using only the DBAL part of Doctrine for my project. So I have to care over the mapping myself. I figured out that Doctrine remaps database types to a generic PHP type as you can read here [1].

Now I came across the fact that Doctrine maps the DB type TinyInt(4) to Boolean. According to the MySQL manual only TinyInt(1) is equivalent to Boolean [2]. Since my project is a legacy one which I like to move from mysqli to Doctrine, I need to stick on the native DB Types.

My question is now how I get the native db type out of Doctrine?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Stefano

[1] http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html
[2] http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html

Comment: can you get the mapping from the current database and make the entites? (with     php doctrine orm:convert-mapping --from-database yml /path/to/mapping-path-converted-to-yml) http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/tools.html#reverse-engineering

Comment: I don't use the ORM, only the DBAL component of Doctrine for now. I found out that Doctrine maps every tinyint (regardless its length) to boolean. So far I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opend up a report in Doctrine issue tracker to figure out why Doctrine works like that. The answer is simple:

The length of TinyInt doesn't say anything about the size of the value which could be stored. Its in any case 1 Byte, but it effects the filling zeros in case you use this option for your field.

Doctrine maps his own boolean type to the mysql tinyint type because MySQL don't provide an own boolean type.

For more informations you can read more on the ticket:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DBAL-781

Comment: Hi, did you found maybe a solution to this problem? I'm too migrating some legacy DB and would like to use it without any modification (for now)

Answer (score -1):

For those who map legacy mysql db to the doctrine I've found solution for common problem that is easy to miss when dealing with TINYINT(4)

**TL;DR**

change `default: '1'` in field mapping to

```
is_active:
    type: boolean
    options:
        default: true
    nullable: true
```

**Long version**

I had the following db structure in legacy DB, please notice **tinyint(4)** in `is_active` column

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foo_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
...
  `is_active` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '1',
...
```

after running the following commands

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeDemoBundle yml
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeDemoBundle
```

and then while running `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`
I ended up with diff while

```
ALTER TABLE foo_table CHANGE is_active is_active TINYINT(1) DEFAULT NULL;
```

I couldn't make any modification to the existing DB (but even doing so didn't solve problem, I was still getting this diff)

yml mapping had following field definition

```
is_active:
    type: boolean
    nullable: true
    default: '1'
    column: is_active
```

I tried with

```
is_active:
    columnDefinition: "TINYINT(4)"
    nullable: true
    default: '1'
    column: is_active
```

without success, then following very common rule in programming *"If you really don't anything wrong with the code then the problem is somewhere else"* I found the solution

**Solution**

```
is_active:
    type: boolean
    options:
        default: true
    nullable: true
```

now, even with using simply `type: boolean` it recognizes tinyint(4) correctly

Comment: Do assume you are using ORM, do you? I didn't figured out how to use a YAML config file only with the DBAL component of Doctrine.